# Good tutorials for materials and lighting in Blender Internal using 2.77a?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I've just recently learned Cycles well enough to get some good renders.  Then found I need to use Blender Internal rendering in order to put the 3D models on the web.

I am really struggling going from Cycles to BI for some reason.  Can't get the materials to work at all.

Seems most tutorials now are for Cycles.  And the BI ones are for older versions and harder to follow.

Can anybody point me to some good tutorials on Blender's Internal Renderer using 2.77a?
Or explain how to use the materials?  I'm after mainly wood and aluminium.

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks